# How to model these object types that can be converted to/from each other, but have different associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, activerecord, model

I have two models that I currently have as STI.

```
class Event
class BlockedTime < Event
class Appointment < Event
```

The models are similar except that 'Appointment' has_one 'client' and has_one 'service', whereas 'BlockedTime' has neither of those associations.

Additionally, I want to be able to convert between the two types easily, and when I search, I'm usually searching on both types together, not one or the other. For those reasons I hesitate to make them separate tables.

For switching between the types, I currently do this in the same form, using the parent 'Event' type, and storing the 'type' as a hidden field, but this is definitely not working out well. I have to do all sorts of conversions in the controller to check validations, etc.

How would you recommend modeling this?

Comment: Do you really need them to be separate models? Seems like a couple of flags would do.

Comment: Could you expand on that? And how would I handle the case of the has_one associations when some of the records won't have one?

Comment: Just thinking out loud. I never used STI so I'm likely wrong. Never mind :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "convert between the two types". It *looks* like STI would be appropriate, this way each model has its own validations and associations, and the underlying class contains the shared properties, meaning there's no need for "conversion".

Comment: The issue with that, is for example: if I edit a 'BlockedTime', the form has a blocked_time object, submitting to the blocked_time controller. But if the user changes it to an 'appointment' in the form (via a radio button), the URL still points to the 'blocked_time' controller which doesn't work b/c it runs the wrong validations.

Comment: It sounds like you have relationship in which `BlockedTime`s are just blocks of time that can be reserved then converted into `Appointment`s. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I were having this problem I would probably model the database differently.

Instead of a **STI/Inheritance** pattern, I would use a **Composition** pattern. So:

```
class Appointment
  belongs_to :block_time, :class_name => "BlockTime"
  ...
end

class BlockTime
   has_one :appointment
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :appointment, :allow_destroy => :true, 
                                               :reject_if => :all_blank

  ...
end
```

**Controller**

```
class AppointmentsController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def new
    @block_time = BlockTime.new
    @block_time.appointment or @block_time.build_appointment
    ...
  end

  def edit
    @block_time = BlockTime.includes(:appointment).find(params[:id])
    @block_time.appointment or @block_time.build_appointment
  end

  ...
end
```

**Form** or at least part of the form

```
<%= f.fields_for :appointment do |g| %>
  <div>
    <%= g.radio_button :_destroy, "1", :checked => !g.object.persisted? %>
    <%= g.label :_destroy_1, "Has no Appointment" %>

    <%= g.radio_button :_destroy, "0", :checked => g.object.persisted? %>
    <%= g.label :_destroy_0, "Has Appointment" %>
  </div>

  <p>
    Client: <%= g.text_field :client %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

This part of the form uses `persisted?` to check to see if the `Appointment` object is a new record or has been persisted to the database. Then if it has been and you want to remove it then it will throw the `_destroy` flag for `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and delete the existing `appointment` association to make it a free `BlockTime`.

Then you could include all the `Appointment` fields in this form too. *You might want to cook up some javascript to disable/enable fields depending on the `radio_button` selection*

Comment: Thanks, but what does BlockTime consist of, just the date/times? And this doesn't seem to solve the association issue of blocked times not having the client, service associations, or am I missing something?

Comment: So `BlockTime` does only store any relevant Date/Time information plus a foreign key, `appointment_id`. Then an `Appointment` would hold the client and service data. In effect an `Appointment` would depend on a `BlockTime`, but a `BlockTime` could also be a standalone record.

Comment: If BlockTime belongs_to :appointment, it can't exist on it's own, can it?

Comment: And how would the controller know the difference between types? As I mentioned, the same form is used to switch between the two types via a radio button.

Comment: Sure a `BlockTime` can exist on its own, just because we have a foreign key doesn't mean we need to use it. Also, with the controller I don't know how your app works so I can't really help you much there, but remember you don't need a 1-to-1:model-to-controller ratio. If I have time I'll update my answer tomorrow to show how **I would** handle the controller.

Comment: Azolo, I assume the form would always create a TimeBlock, and I could check the radio button to see if it should also have an associated appointment? I bet there's a better way so I'd appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much my thoughts except I thought about it and I think it would be easier if an `Appointment` held the foreign key to `BlockTime` since there is always a `BlockTime`. I'm updating the answer with a short implementation now.